# Why isn't the set $A=\{x \in l_{\infty}: x=\bigg(\frac{\xi_i}{i}\bigg)_{i\in \mathbb{N} }, (\xi_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \in l_{\infty} \}$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

I tried to find a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$ which converges to some $y \notin A$ but I couldn't see a clear way to do it.

Any hints?

Comment: Try finding a sequence converging to $(1/\sqrt i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $x_i = 1/\sqrt{i}$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$ is in $l_\infty$ but not in $A$ since constructing this sequence wold require taking $\xi_i = \sqrt i$ which is not in $l_\infty$.

However, the sequences $x^{(j)}_i = 1/\sqrt{i}$ for $i \le j$ and $x^{(j)}_i = 0$ for $i > j$ are in $A$ and converge to the above sequence.